# on click .. Suspicious link error in gmail(laravel)

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

When a user signs up on our website, they get an email verification link, but whenever they try to click on any link in that mail, they get the alert error message:

> Suspicious link
>
> This link leads to an untrusted site. Are you sure you want to
> proceed?

We are using the sendgrid mailer system and we are certified to https.

Where is the problem coming from?

Comment: Whats the link? Ususally that is a ssl problem.

Comment: signup activation link, website link and other links

Comment: We have a test server website and live website, in test server it's not getting any error but in live website only when user clicks on activation link its showing that error

Comment: Like I said I would check the ssl. It is a https link, right?

Comment: check URL in env file.

Comment: In order to authenticating your domain please go to postmaster.google.com , this just helped me to authenticate my domain

Answer (score 8):

This is mostly in newsletters(Mailers), we need to verify the domain in Google

For authenticating domain using the steps below:

1. Go to [postmaster.google.com](http://postmaster.google.com).
2. On the bottom-right, click the + button.
3. In the box that pops up, enter your authentication domain.
4. Next, prove that you own the domain by adding a [DNS TXT](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895) or a [DNS CNAME](https://support.google.com/a/answer/47283) record.

For reference: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/xSV6J-Nmkmc;context-place=forum/apps

Also it happens when we have https(ssl) but we are using the link http

Comment: I did already and it returns "verified" nevertheless I still get this crapy message from GMAIL. DMARK SPF etc: are all ok.

Answer (score 5):

We were recently having this issue in our account verification emails as well. Verifying our domain through DNS records as recommended by Google was not enough.

The ultimate solution for us was ensuring that every link has an `alt` tag with descriptive text.

```
<a href="https://example.com/verify" alt="Click here to verify your account">Verify!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check once for a DNS record. You can check it from below url

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

And also check for the DMARK record which is found in your mx records or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to sendgrid.com > Settings > Sender Authentication and configure DNS